# functions not being logged or called in the following code tests

Tags: javascript, function, frontend

I've been testing my code a couple of times now and I've been getting the same errors in the output :

```
Failed Test 1: Not logging the consoleStyler() variables
Passed Test 2: successfully logged celebrateStyler() variables
Failed Test 3: Not calling consoleStyler() and celebrateStyler()
Failed Test 4: Not calling styleAndCelebrate()
```

with the code that I have here :

```js
function consoleStyler(color, background, fontSize, txt) {
    var message = "%c" + txt;
    
    var style = `color: ${color}`;
    style += `background: ${background}`;
    style += `font-size: ${fontSize}`;

    console.log(message, style);
}

function celebrateStyler(reason) {
    var fontStyle = "color: tomato; font-size: 50px";

    if (reason == "birthday") {
        console.log(`%cHappy birthday`, fontStyle);
    } else if (reason == "champions") {
        console.log(`%cCongrats on the title!`, fontStyle);
    } else {
        console.log("no message and style is provided");
    }
}

function styleAndCelebrate(color, background, fontSize, txt, reason) {
    consoleStyler(color, background, fontSize, txt);
    celebrateStyler(reason);
}

consoleStyler('#1d5c63', '#ede6db', '40px', 'Congrats!');
celebrateStyler('birthday');
styleAndCelebrate('ef7c8e', 'fae8e0', '30px', 'You made it!', 'champions');
```

here's the complete output that I have for the functions :

```
Congrats!
undefined
Happy birthday
undefined
You made it!
Congrats on the title!
undefined
```

I’m confused about where I’m not calling/referring to the functions and its variables and will need some assistance on this please, thanks.

Comment: You need to tag this with your unit testing framework and show the test harness.

Comment: I clearly see the problem looking at the output in the snipplet console. Your styles are formatted wrong. Look at the logs with the ones that work vs the ones that don't. Do you see what you missed in your string concatenation?

Answer (score 2):

### A simple missing semicolon in the CSS properties

It might be the cause of failure of task 1 followed by other linked  tasks 3 and 4. Always separate the properties of CSS via semicolon (so inside back-ticks simply add a semicolon at end).

##### your code

```
var style = `color: ${color}`;
    style += `background: ${background}`;
    style += `font-size: ${fontSize}`;
```

##### correction needed

```
var style = `color: ${color};`;
    style += `background: ${background};`;
    style += `font-size: ${fontSize};`;
```

##### Entire Corrected code :-

```
 
function consoleStyler(color, background, fontSize, txt) {
  var message = "%c" + txt;
  var style = `color: ${color};`;
  style += `font-size: ${fontSize};`;
  console.log(message, style);
}


function celebrateStyler(reason) {
  var fontStyle = "color: tomato; font-size: 50px";
  if (reason == "birthday") {
    console.log(`%cHappy birthday`, fontStyle);
  } else if (reason == "champions") {
    console.log(`%cCongrats on the title!`, fontStyle);
  } else {
    console.log("no message and style is provided");
  }
}


function styleAndCelebrate(color, background, fontSize, txt, reason) {
  consoleStyler(color, background, fontSize, txt);
  celebrateStyler(reason);
}


consoleStyler("#1d5c63", "#ede6db", "40px", "Congrats!");
celebrateStyler("birthday");
styleAndCelebrate("#ef7c8e", "#fae8e0", "30px", "You made it!", "champions");
```

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

In your function ***consoleStyler***, you missed adding the semicolon in your var style.

**Your code:**

```
function consoleStyler(color, background, fontSize, txt) {
var message = "%c" + txt;

var style = `color: ${color}`;
style += `background: ${background}`;
style += `font-size: ${fontSize}`;

console.log(message, style);
```

}

**Correction**

```
function consoleStyler(color, background, fontSize, txt) {
var message = "%c" + txt
var style = `color: ${color};`
style += `background: ${background};`
style += `font-size: ${fontSize};`
console.log(message, style)
```

}

By adding the semicolon, you're separating each CSS declaration to be applied by the following "style +=", since is part of the concatenating string. Like in CSS, if you don't add a semicolon at the end of each declaration, you will get an error.

If you need a different visual approach. This helps to see how your code is applying styles in the console.log();

This is like in CSS:

```
.consoleStyler {
color: #ef7c8e;
background: #fae8e0;
font-size: 30px;
```

}